# How to replace parts of a string with a react component multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

How could I replace parts of the string again with another react component? Here's a theorical example, that doesn't work of course... But it's self explanatory

```
const text = "hello world";
const parts = text.split(" ");

temp1 = parts.map(part => {
  return part.match(/hello/) ?
          `<b>${part}</b>` :          
          part.match(/world/) ?
          `<i>${part}</i>`:
          part
})
text1 = `<div>${temp1.join(' ')}</div>`;

console.log(text1)
```

Result: `<div><b>hello</b> <i>world</i></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start without React and trying to break down what you are doing (I will use strings instead of jsx):

```js
let text = "hello world";
let reg, parts;

reg = new RegExp(/hello/);
parts = text.split(reg);
temp1 = parts.map(part => part.match(reg) ? `<b>${part}</b>` : part)
text1 = `<div>${temp1}</div>`;

reg = new RegExp(/world/);
parts = text.split(reg);
temp2 = parts.map(part => part.match(reg) ? `<i>${part}</i>` : part)
text2 = `<div>${temp2}</div>`;

console.log(text1)
console.log(text2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The output is:

```
<div>, world</div>
<div>hello ,</div>
```

Is this what you want? I am assuming not.

By the way, just so you know, when you create your parts array `parts = text.split(reg);`

you receive firstly an array like `["", " world"]` and secondly like: `["hello ", ""]`

I don't think this is what you expect or at least it doesn't help achieve the output I think you want to?

Let's assume you actually want this as the output? - let's call it "A":

```
<div><b>hello</b> <i>world</i></div>
```

Or maybe you want this? (not very clear from your question) - let's call it "B":

```
<div><b>hello</b></div>
<div><i>world</i></div>
```

so let's try to achieve A:

```js
const text = "hello world";
const parts = text.split(" ");

temp1 = parts.map(part => {
  return part.match(/hello/) ?
          `<b>${part}</b>` :          
          part.match(/world/) ?
          `<i>${part}</i>`:
          part
})
text1 = `<div>${temp1.join(' ')}</div>`;

console.log(text1)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Output (A):

```
<div><b>hello</b> <i>world</i></div>
```

Now let's try B:

```js
const text = "hello world";
const parts = text.split(" ");

temp1 = parts.map(part => {
  return part.match(/hello/) ?
          `<b>${part}</b>` :          
          part.match(/world/) ?
          `<i>${part}</i>`:
          part
})
text1 = temp1.map(part => {
  return `<div>${part}</div>`
})

console.log(text1.join('\n'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Output (B):

```
<div><b>hello</b></div>
<div><i>world</i></div>
```

Please edit your question to explain exactly what output you are looking for.

**Update, after the question was edited now it's clear what the desired output is so I'll put that into react now:**

It doesn't seem to work on the stack overflow snippet,

But it does work in codePen: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/VwLGzpJ

Output:

[image]

[image]

```js
function Example() {
  const text = "hello world";
  const modText = text.replace(/ /g, ", ");
  const parts = modText.split(",");

  return (
    <>
      {parts.map(part => {
        return part.match(/hello/) ? (
          <b>{part}</b>
        ) : part.match(/world/) ? (
          <i>{part}</i>
        ) : (
          part
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
```

Comment: I updated my answer to also show you how to do it in React for your desired output. Please consider to up-vote and mark as correct answer if I helped you solve your problem. Thanks. https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/VwLGzpJ

Comment: You're a legend, amazing.

Comment: Glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    const regex = <-any regex-!>
    const result =
        string.replaceAll(regex, "#$1#")
        .split("#")
        .map((v) => {
          return list.includes(value) ? (
            <>
              <Tooltip title={value}>
                <b>{value}</b>
              </Tooltip>
            </>
          ) : (
             value 
          );
        });
```

Split by some character(here '#') so that it wont affect other use cases of empty characters